# IntelliJ IDEA - Show method help/description

Tags: intellij-idea

I was wondering if there is a way to see the description/help of a method on the list of suggestions like in Eclipse. And going to the class and looking up the help manually isn't an option.

Example in Eclipse:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you select an item in the suggestion list and want to see its documentation, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (Q = quick information) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Button3 Click</kbd>. The popup will be updated automatically if you select another item in the list.

[image: Quick info]

Similar you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to see its quick definition, that is its code. Very handy.

For that to work, add the path to the JavaDoc in the project settings. Here I have set it to the online Java 7 documentation:

[image: Doc path]

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac - tried both the Ctrl and Cmd keys.

Comment: Cmd(or Alt)-P on MacOS

Comment: ^J on Mac. ^ stands for Control.

Answer (score 3):

Press F1 and IntelliJ will present a popup with detailed information about whatever the current cursor is on. For a method, that will include things like a general description, parameters, and errors thrown.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be a bug in `Python` project.

The `Quick Documentation` **shortcut** sometimes work, sometimes do not work.

Try **import another module**, or **remove an exists import**, then the shortcut may work again.

So, make sure the shortcut worked in a normal `Java` project first, or **IntelliJ** *IDEA* will waste your much time on it.